# Multiple Key Presses in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, keyboard

I am having trouble updating keysPressed when two keys are pressed at once. I have the following code, which works perfectly when only one key is pressed.

```
  const keysPressed = {'w':false, 'a':false, 's':false, 'd':false};

  document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      keysPressed[event.key] = true;
  });

  document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
      keysPressed[event.key] = false;
  });

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(keysPressed))
  }
```

Comment: it would work correctly, lets take an example , you are pressing `shift+ A`, then first two `key down` events occur, and then two `key up` events occur. It works fine right, what other behaviour do you want it to be?

Comment: if I hold "a" and "b" down, then the console would either log "a" or "b" to be true but not both

Comment: ya i understood, i checked, then add only  a key up event listener, then if you hold "a"  or "b", it would not console.log() but, when u release both, it would console.log().I think there is no key even which listens to both the key events at a time, it is better to use keyup only. even key press and key down fails here.